# `QuickPDFAX0726.PDFLibrary': Class not registered ' Error

Tags: php, apache, pdf

I am Using QuickPdf Library ,Install QuickPDF 7.26 Successfully.
then i register the `QuickPDFAX0726.dll` by using `sysWOW64/cmd.exe` then DLLRegistered succeed message shown.

when I am trying to create an com object by using below code

```
    $a=new COM('QuickPDFAX0726.PDFLibrary');
```

Error Shown "Fatal error: Uncaught exception `com_exception` with message

> Failed to create COM object QuickPDFAX0726.PDFLibrary: Class not registered

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check:

- Whether the system is 32-bit or 64-bit.
- QuickPDF version.

If QuickPDF  version is less than 8.16 and your system is 64-bit, then it will not work. 
Upgrade QuickPDF to version 8.16 or higher.